# I have difficulty parsing in nginx from which source IP 404 request are coming

Tags: bash, nginx

```bash
awk -F\” ‘($2 ~ “/survey/report/na”){print $1}’ access.log.1 | awk ‘{print $1}’ | sort | uniq -c | sort –r
```

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

```bash
awk -F\" '($2 ~ "/survey/report/na"){print $1}' access.log.1 | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort –r
```

```
sort: cannot read: –r: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone try help with the parsing how exactly I can fetch from which IP 404 request is coming from

Comment: Try running first command alone and inspect the output, then pipe the first command to second only and inspect the output, then add the third command and inspect the otput - until you find out what is wrong.